# Extracting specific subplots from corner plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a corner plot (1-sigma constraints) which I produced with my own script.
It basically works based on the following

```
labels = my_params
for i in range(len(my_params)):
        for j in range(i):
            ax = plt.subplot(len(my_params)-1, len(my_params)-1 , (i - 1)*(len(my_params)-1) + (j+1))
            if i == len(my_params) - 1:
                ax.set_xlabel(labels[j], size='x-small')

            else:
                ax.set_xticklabels([])
            if j == 0:
                ax.set_ylabel(labels[i], size='x-small')

            else:
                ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

where `my_params` is the list of parameters I have and `plot` is a function of mine that draws a specific object in the subplot.

Say `my_params` has 11 elements, `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j , l`, I would like now to plot only the subplots corresponding to `a, b, c, d, i, j`. How can I extract those subplots and

Comment: Make a new list with just those parameters?  Remove the unwanted parameters from the list?

Comment: The code you show is a 2D grid. What does a single parameter (e.g. `b`) signify in this 2D grid? (Mind that often an image is better than 1000 words, but at least describe clearly what you want to do, and also where exactly the problem lies, i.e. what hinders you to achieve your goal (that often helps to understand the actual problem).